# Shrinking HTML content without viewport

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, viewport

We have a web based LOB application and currently we are shrinking the content of the app when it goes onto a smaller resolution browser i.e. IPad, using the viewport. using javascript:

```
    document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute(
          'content',
          'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8');
```

This works fine asthecially but it seems to produce a performance hit when the browser has to scale everything down, especially with our kendo controls (the grid takes a massive hit).

Just wondering if anyone can advice a better was to scale down the viewport without hitting any performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if you're getting a performance hit from scaling the page since that happens on the GPU and is expected to be very fast.

Additionally, your viewport descriptor as-is wont scale the page unless you have content that's explicitly wider than your layout size (for example, a very wide image). The browser will automatically zoom out to show all the content on load so your best bet is to pick a good layout width for your page (e.g. `width=1200`) and not set an initial-scale. `width=device-width` will attempt to lay your page out into the size of the device's screen, which is not what you want if you're trying to scale your page down.